# Class associated with an interface or abstract class

Tags: java, uml

I have a trouble with understanding how a class can associate ( or have a composition relation ) with an interface or an abstract class.
As far as i know, i cannot initiate an interface ( nor abstract class ).

How does this relation work and how can i use the class that has a composition relation with an interface?  As i have attached below.

Another question: If i want to extend button class to a new class ( KeyBoard ), how the composition relation will effect on the KeyBoard class? Do i need to implement the interface? Can i ignore it?

[image: Composition relation of button and button server]

Thank you

Comment: Is my answer ok for you ?

Comment: why do you ask but never take care of answers nor remarks (not only here) ?

Answer (score 1):

Simply spoken: You can not instantiate `ButtonServer` but you *can* instantiate `SendButtonServer`. And that will aggregate `Button`s.

When you subclass `Button` the `SendButtonServer` can use only what is defined in `Button` but nothing else. If you need your subclasses in `SendButtonServer` you would need to change the definition and replace `Button`. But how is not clear as per your question.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a trouble with understanding how a class can associate ( or have a composition relation ) with an iterface or an abstract class. As far as i know, i cannot initiate an interface ( nor abstract class ).
>
> How does this relation work and how can i use the class that has a composition relation with an interface?

yes they cannot have instance, but in fact the *effective* type of the associated element is one of the sub types.

Example :

```
interface ButtonServer {
  public void buttonPressed();
};

class SendButtonAdapter implements ButtonServer {
  public void buttonPressed() {
    System.out.println("SendButtonAdapter buttonPressed");
  }
}

class DigitButtonAdapter implements ButtonServer {
  public void buttonPressed() {
    System.out.println("DigitButtonAdapter buttonPressed");
  }
}

class Button {
  private ButtonServer server;

  public Button(ButtonServer b) {
    server = b;
  }

  void pressed() {
    server.buttonPressed();
  }
}

class Main {
  public static void main(String argv[]) {
    Button b1 = new Button(new SendButtonAdapter());

    b1.pressed();

    Button b2 = new Button(new DigitButtonAdapter());

    b2.pressed();
  }
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ javac Main.java 
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ java Main
SendButtonAdapter buttonPressed
DigitButtonAdapter buttonPressed
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

> Another question: If i want to extend button class to a new class ( KeyBoard ), how the composition relation will effect on the KeyBoard class? Do i need to implement the interface? Can i ignore it?

It seems the domain is a phone, so *Button* is a key and *KeyBoard* will not inherits/implements *ButtonServer* because that have no sense, but you have an association *KeyBoard* -1----n_keys- *Button*